# C#: How to register a function from all subclasses of an interface to a single event in least redundant manner

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, event-handling

Implementing Unity3D, I have an event `FrameUpdateEventHandler` that triggers every frame update:

```
public delegate void FrameUpdateEventHandler(float deltaTime);

public class API
{
    public static FrameUpdateEventHandler FrameUpdateEvent;

    public void OnFrameUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {
        if(FrameUpdateEvent != null) FrameUpdateEvent(deltaTime);
    }
}

//Included as a script  in a single Unity component
public class UnityScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        API.OnFrameUpdate(Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I also have an interface `Entity` that contains a function intended to be used as an event handler for `API.FrameUpdateEvent`

```
public interface Entity
{
    public void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime);
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is **to have every instance of a subclass of `Entity` listen on `API.FrameUpdateEvent`**.

Though the simple answer is to do this for every implementation,

```
public class Dog : Entity
{
    public Dog()
    {
        API.FrameUpdateEvent += FrameUpdate;
    }

    public void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {

    }
}
```

It feels repetitive after you go through many different `Entity`s:

```
public class Cat : Entity
{
    public Cat()
    {
        API.FrameUpdateEvent += FrameUpdate;
    }

    public void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {

    }
}

public class Bird : Entity
{
    public Bird()
    {
        API.FrameUpdateEvent += FrameUpdate;
    }

    public void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {

    }
}
```

I have a very strong feeling like I'm missing something that would make this process a lot less redundant.

Here are some ideas that would make it less redundant (at least in my opinion), but isn't possible to the extent of my knowledge:

- **Mark `Entity.FrameUpdate(float)` somehow to automatically be added to `API.FrameUpdateEvent` as an event handler**
- **Add `FrameUpdateEvent` into `Event` as an event, but somehow link it back to `API.FrameUpdateEvent` so that it responds to `API.OnFrameUpdate(float)`**

  ```
  public interface Entity
  {
      event FrameUpdateEventHandler FrameUpdateEvent;

      public void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime);
  }

  public class Dog : Entity
  {
      public event FrameUpdateEventHandler FrameUpdateEvent;

      public Dog()
      {
          //API.OnFrameUpdate() wouldn't trigger this, afaik
          FrameUpdateEvent += FrameUpdate;
      }

      public void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime)
      {

      }
  }
  ```

Anyway, the bottom line is that I'm unsure whether or not I'm approaching the problem the wrong way, so feel free to suggest changing the model I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use an abstract class instead of an interface.**

If your types that implement the `Entity` interface aren't inheriting from other classes already, you can make `Entity` an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        API.FrameUpdateEvent += FrameUpdate;
    }

    public abstract void FrameUpdate(float deltaTime);
}
```

Putting the `abstract` keyword on the method essentially makes it work the same as an interface: it requires subclasses to implement it rather than providing an implementation of its own.

Comment: I feel like I have to explain why `Entity` is an interface. Well, long story short, there is already an abstract class that implements `Entity` named `UnityEntity` (I abstracted the API to not directly implement Unity3D), where I can possibly register `FrameUpdate()` as you say. 

I have an itching feeling to keep `Entity` an interface but if it's the only choice I can make it abstract as well. +1 though, doing this would solve most of my concerns.

Comment: @Octopod If you already have a class that implements `Entity` that all your other classes inherit from then you just add the event handler there.